# Merge two Reporting Services datasets into one

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have two datasets from two different databases in my report. And the datasets have the same columns. How can i merge these datasets into one Dataset

I need some thing like this,

```
SELECT A,B,C FROM DATASET1
UNION
SELECT A,B,C FROM DATASET2
```

Comment: If that is what you need, you could just do that in your SQL of your dataset

Comment: I cannot do that they are from two different servers and cannot create a linked server between them

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no equivalent in SSRS of creating a UNION from datasets coming from linked servers. Other similar questions get similar responses (e.g. [this one](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/352b6b01-47e9-4fb7-9f79-12ed62b2f53b/union-multiple-datasets?forum=sqlreportingservices)).

Some workarounds could include using `LookupSet`, [creating complex tablixes](http://www.sqlcircuit.com/2012/03/ssrs-2008-r2-lookup-how-to-use-multiple.html), and simply *faking* the union by having two identical tablixes below eachother, the second one not having any headers. Other than that you'll just have to union on the data-side itself, and not in SSRS.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen. The links are really helpful. but for my purpose the lookupSet or having an two table one without column header won't help. Since I need to also sort by one of the columns.

Comment: Both the 1 and 2 link are now dead links.

Comment: @Zack Thx for the heads up. Link 1 still worked for me, but link 2 indeed seemed dead. I've rewritten the answer accordingly. The core of the answer remains though: no such thing as a true "union" for data sets in SSRS.