# merge two mdx queries

Tags: mdx

I have two MDX queries.

First query :

```
SELECT {[Measures].[Actual]} ON 0,
{ DESCENDANTS([Dim Office].[Offices].[Office Level 02].ALLMEMBERS)
*DESCENDANTS([Dim Business Line].[Business Lines].[Business Line Level 02].ALLMEMBERS)
*{[Dim Date].[Fiscal Dim Date Calculations].&[Current Dim Date]}} ON 1
FROM
[BI]
```

Second one :

```
SELECT {[Measures].[Actual]} ON 0,
{ DESCENDANTS([Dim Office].[Offices].[Office Level 02].ALLMEMBERS)
*[Dim PNL].[PNL].&[6]
*{[Dim Date].[Fiscal Dim Date Calculations].&[Current Dim Date]}} ON 1
FROM
[BI]
```

How can I get the union of the two queries ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a workaround, you could use T-SQL EXEC statement to make such thing. Please check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28103579/mdx-ca-2100-security-issue/28317052#28317052), to find the way to query AS server from SQL server. In short, you just need two temp tables:

```
declare @tsqlquery1 varchar(1000) = ...
declare @mdxquery1 varchar(1000) = ''' SELECT {[Measures].[Actual]} ON 0,
 { DESCENDANTS([Dim Office].[Offices].[Office Level 02].ALLMEMBERS)
   *DESCENDANTS([Dim Business Line].[Business Lines].[Business Line Level 02].ALLMEMBERS)
 *{[Dim Date].[Fiscal Dim Date Calculations].&[Current Dim Date]}} ON 1
 FROM
 [BI])'''' + ''' + ')'

 -- same for second mdx
 ...
 -- add temp tables
 create table #t1 (...)
 create table #t2 (...)

 -- insert MDX results into temp table1
 insert into #t1
 EXEC(@tsqlquery1 + @mdxquery1)

 -- insert MDX results into temp table2
 insert into #t2
 EXEC(@tsqlquery2 + @mdxquery2)

 -- get union
 select * from #t1 union select * from #t2
```

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
SET1 as
{ DESCENDANTS([Dim Office].[Offices].[Office Level 02].ALLMEMBERS)
*DESCENDANTS([Dim Business Line].[Business Lines].[Business Line Level 02].ALLMEMBERS)
*{[Dim Date].[Fiscal Dim Date Calculations].&[Current Dim Date]}}
SET2 as
{ DESCENDANTS([Dim Office].[Offices].[Office Level 02].ALLMEMBERS)
*[Dim PNL].[PNL].&[6]
*{[Dim Date].[Fiscal Dim Date Calculations].&[Current Dim Date]}}

SET3 as 
Union(SET1,SET2)

select  {[Measures].[Actual]} ON 0,
SET3 on 1
From [BI]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to concatenate the results of both queries, **this is not possible in MDX**. MDX is a strongly typed language, and a report has to have the same structure with regard to hierarchy on all axes. And your row axes differ: the first uses `[Dim Business Line].[Business Lines]` as the second hierarchy, and the second uses `[Dim PNL].[PNL]` as the second hierarchy.

You should concatenate both results in the client tool that you are using.

Comment: It there a workaround to do it ? I need to get results for pnl and business line in the same matrix ?

Comment: @user138957 There is no workaround on the MDX side. Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19285962/merge-two-reporting-services-datasets-into-one and the posts linked from there give you some ideas for workarounds on the report side.