# How to Join data from two datasets together in a matrix

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have an `OPEN_TICKET` and `CLOSED_TICKET` datasets and was wondering how i would be able to join the two together in a matrix.

I was somewhat able to achieve what I needed and display this output:

```
                   |      8 |         9 |      10 |       11 | etc... |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Total Open Tickets | 5645   | 6546      | 745     | 8451     | etc... |
```

I did this by creating a `Column Group` of `INCIDENT_OPEN_DATE` (the numbered headers) and then for the row doing an expression of `RowCount()` on my `Column Group` by referencing it like this: `RowCount("MY_COLUMN_GROUP_NAME")`.

The matrix that I have shown above shows the total tickets open from the date they were opened.

I now would like to show under the same months, the total tickets closed in that that month. I was able to get a similar output as above but just with the closed tickets and using the `INCIDENT_CLOSED_DATE`

```
                     |      8 |         9 |
-------------------------------------------
Total Closed Tickets | 1863   | 7985      |
```

But I would ultimately like to have everything under one matrix like this:

```
                     |      8 |         9 |      10 |       11 | etc... |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total Open Tickets   | 5645   | 6546      | 745     | 8451     | etc... |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total Closed Tickets | 1863   | 7985      | 0       | 0        | etc... |
```

Sorry for the vague question, but this is my first time using SSRS and running queries is not my strongest area. What would be the best way to achieve this in my matrix report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use the `Union`  and format your data before it comes to the `SSRS` but if you have no control over to the data then only way you can achieve this is using the `LookUp`. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ee210531.aspx) is the more information on this.

For your requirement the expressions can be used as below, (Not tested, may be need to change according to your needs)

```
 =Lookup(Fields!INCIDENT_OPEN_DATE .Value, Fields!INCIDENT_OPEN_DATE .Value, RowCount("MY_COLUMN_GROUP_NAME"), "CLOSED_TICKET")
```

But there is catch `LookUp` is supports `SSRS 2008 r2` and above servers not to the previous ones. Because I was trying to do the same thing in report but my server was `2008` so `Lookup` doesn't supported me . If your server is older that `SSRS 2008 r2` then let me know because there is another trick that can be used in place of `LookUp`. But that is complicated so If you need I can post it here. Just let me know.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am going to reformat my data before it comes into `SSRS`. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This is not a full answer. (There is not enough details unfortunately).
But a suggestion is to UNION a second query (total closed tickets) with your first (total open tickets, and that will put the results in the same dataset.

So something like this

```
Select 'Total open tickets',1,2,3...etc
from Table
Where...
Union
Select 'total closed tickets',1,2,3... etc (the same qty of columns)
from table
where....
```

I hope this helps in the right direction.

Roger

Comment: Roger -  how would I go about using a `Union` in SSRS? Also, what other information would you need to answer my question? I would be more than happy to provide what is needed.

Comment: Sorry, I was too vague myself.... you should use the SQL union to create the new combined dataset to be used in SSRS.  Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19285962/merge-two-reporting-services-datasets-into-one